# I can not plot dat file

Tags: python, file, plot

I try to plot ecg with .dat file. to plot the ecg I use wfdb and this code:

```
import wfdb 
record = wfdb.rdsamp('mitdb/100', sampto=3000) 
annotation = wfdb.rdann('mitdb/100', 'atr', sampto=3000) 
wfdb.plotrec(record, 
     title='Record 100 from MIT-BIH Arrhythmia Database .dat form',
     timeunits = 'seconds', figsize = (10,4), ecggrids = 'all')
```

but I have this error:

> wfdb.plotrec(record,   AttributeError: module 'wfdb' has no attribute
>   'plotrec'

Answer (score 0):

Same issue has occurred here as well. Removed the existing wfdb

```
pip uninstall wfdb
```

then installed the wfdb version 1.3.9

```
pip install wfdb==1.3.9
```

worked for me.